# Interface Builder Accessibility Label Spanning Multiple Elements

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, accessibility

Does anyone know of a way to have a single value for an accessibility label span across multiple elements?  I have two labels that form a single title line and the screen reader reads them separately.  I have tried selecting both and applying the setting and it doesn't work.

EDIT:

Here is a view of my storyboard...

[image: Storyboard accessibility settings]

However, when the screen readers reaches this point, it reads the first label (not using the accessibility value) and then the second label.

[image]

Comment: hey can you post some code, screenshots? anything to explain your problem more...

Comment: Not familiar with the program you're working with, but is there a way to either combine them into one element or wrap them with one element and point the label to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group elements using `UIAccessibilityElement` class and provide a combined frame of the elements you want to group using `accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace` property.

```
//From Apple Docs
let profileElement = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: headerView)
profileElement.accessibilityLabel = profileNameLabel.text
profileElement.accessibilityValue = openPostsLabel.text
profileElement.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitButton     // Tells VoiceOver to treat our new view like a button

let combinedLabelFrame = profileNameLabel.frame.union(openPostsLabel.frame)
let profileElementFrame = combinedLabelFrame.union(profileImageView.frame) //providing union of frames.
// This tells VoiceOver where the element is on screen so a user can find it as they touch around for elements
profileElement.accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace = profileElementFrame
```

Check apple docs [Whats new in accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/215/).

Link for [sample app](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/making-apps-accessible.zip) explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I had two labels in a `UIStackView` - so I disabled the accessibility on the actual labels and then enabled accessibility for the stack view. In Xcode 10, `UIStackView` does not have an "Accessibility" section in Interface Builder, so what I did is add two custom attributes under *Identity Inspector > User Defined Runtime Attributes*. I added a `Bool` named `isAccessibilityElement` set to `true` and a `String` named `accessibilityLabel` set to my desired text. Of course if you want this to update programatically, you can create an `IBOutlet` to the `UIStackView` and set the values in code.

Answer (score -2):

I ended up solving this issue...

I set the label value of the first element to "Transfection Search" and cleared and disabled the accessibility settings on the second.  This way, the screen reader reads the first items value and completely skips the second.

It still only highlights the first element, but I don't think there is a way to group elements and apply accessibility attributes to all.